# GSL libray and header paths

Tags: 14.04, svn

I am trying to install a package which has a dependecy on gsl. In the package docs, it is mentioned:

```
0. This installation is known to work easily if you use Mac OS X and have 
installed python and gsl using MacPorts.

1. Modify the setup_cfg.py
Change the 'GSL_INCLUDE' and 'GSL_LIB' variables to your path to the GSL
header and library files. For example:
GSL_INCLUDE = 'some_path/gsl-1.15/include'
GSL_LIB = 'some_path/gsl-1.15/lib'
```

I am using ubuntu and installed gsl using

```
sudo apt-get install libgsl0-dev
```

How can I find the gsl libraries path? 'some_path/gsl-1.15/include' ; 'some_path/gsl-1.15/lib'

```
abhishek:/usr/lib$ pkg-config --libs gsl 
-lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
```

Comment: Why are you following instructions for LFS if you are using Ubuntu? You can install the GSL development package `libgsl0-dev` directly from the repository.

Comment: I know. Either way I want the path. The other also renders the same result.

Comment: If you've installed libgsl0-dev from the repository, then you should be able to link the libraries using `pkg-config --libs gsl`. The actual libraries should be in the standard search path `/usr/lib`.

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks for the reply! Please check this: `abhishek:/usr/lib$ pkg-config` `--libs gsl
-lgsl -lgslcblas -lm`

Comment: @steeldriver Made major changes in question to make it more clear and understandable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you installed the `libgsl0-dev` package, then its header files should have gone in `/usr/include/gsl` and its libraries in `/usr/lib`

You can confirm this by looking at the output of the command `dpkg -L libgsl0-dev` or by looking at the list of files online at http://packages.ubuntu.com

I don't think it is possible to know from what you have posted whether the software you are installing is expecting the `gsl` subdirectory - that is, whether it wants

```
GSL_INCLUDE = '/usr/include/gsl'
```

or just

```
GSL_INCLUDE = '/usr/include'
```

(in C-language terms, that would be the difference between something like `#include <gsl/cblas.h>` and `#include <cblas.h>`). You may need to try both.

Note that `/usr/include` and `/usr/lib` are standard search paths for tools such as `gcc`. Most often, when development packages install to such paths there is no need to set them explicitly - you will see that `pkg-config --cflags --libs` does not output any `-I` or `-L` include path or library path directives.